# Creating custom button in kendo editor

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-editor

I'm using `kendo editor`. when i want to create list of items for multi line, facing a problem(see image)

[image]
for solving this problem, I'm create custom button:

```
 {
                name: "custom",
                tooltip: "Insert a List",
                exec: function(e) {
                    var editor = $(this).data("kendoEditor");
                    var selectedText = editor.getSelection().toString();
                    if (selectedText.length > 0) {
                        var list = selectedText.split("\n").join("</li><li>");
                        list = "<ul><li>" + list.substring(0, list.length - 5) + "</ul>";
                    }
                    editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: list });
                }
            }
```

This code works fine when select whole text of line but when select just part of a line(not whole line just some character of line), list items not created from starting point of line.

Comment: Can you reproduce that in [dojo.telerik.com](http://dojo.telerik.com/) ?

Comment: Check this. http://dojo.telerik.com/adILA

Comment: You mean like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNhKl.png).. if you select the text no entirely(item 1) the list is created wrong(item 2) while it should be created like item 3. Is that right?

Comment: (image 1) and (image 2) is correct but in this sample,I want create list just for item 1 and 2(when '333' not selected, no list create for them). result will be:
.111
.222
333

Comment: Like in image 2, it should create for the whole `222`, and not broken, right?

Comment: absolutely yes.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing `toString()` over the Selection object, you need to work with the Selection and Range APIs in order to obtain the complete text nodes and then apply the splitting.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range

Comment: I think with `Range` and `Selection` just can get selected text, not all text. In this problem we need find selected text in full text.